# How to get the end_date using Laravel Cashier?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I am trying to get the end_date of Stripe subscription.

I have in my view:

```
@if (Auth::user()->subscription('main')->onGracePeriod())
    <p> Your subscription will end on: {{ Auth::user()->subscribed('main')->ends_at }}</p>
@endif
```

And obviously that is not working because I get:

```
Call to a member function ends_at() on boolean
```

My User Class:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, EntrustUserTrait, Billable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'trial_ends_at'
    ];
}
```

My migrations so you have an idea on the tables:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
            $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        });

        Schema::create('subscriptions', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('stripe_id');
            $table->string('stripe_plan');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Again looking for end_date listed in the subscriptions table in the DB. I could always query it using this table but wanted to see if there was a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the Subscription model's ends_at date property using: `Auth::user()->subscription('main')->endsAt`

Comment: that worked . Thanks